# TabHost Android make Text Bold

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-style-tabhost

I m looking for way to text Bold, basically Tab Host make Text Bold.

Sample image is as below

[image]

Below is my code.

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
        {
            if (tabId.equals("READING")) 
            {
                for(int i=0;i< tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
                {
                    //unselected
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E6A9EC")); 
                }
                // selected
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0;i< tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
                {
                 //unselected
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E6A9EC"));
                }
                // selected
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
   });
```

Comment: Do you mean make the selected item bold, or all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can style it in your custom theme change

```
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@android:style/Widget.TabWidget</item>
```

and

```
<style name="Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>  


<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/tab_indicator_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear where I should be adding the codes. I did that in styles.xml and it is not working. Is there a way do it in JAVA ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the easiest way: 
After you add the tab to your TabHost do the following:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
```

'i' is just an index to the new tab. In my case I was using a for loop. 
After that it's very simple, just do this:

```
textView .setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Hope this helps.